GLMM with cumulative distances
I have calculated the cumulative distances travelled for each individual. The objective is to represent the data in a graph with a tendency curve using the R package ggplot2. However, the data are too heterogeneous, which has resulted in an inacurate trend line and a decrease at times. I wanted to know whether it would be useful to check whether it is possible to use a generalised linear mixed effects model (GLMM) or a model to represent the differences between men and women, and to test them.
The following data frame is representative of the data in question:
library(ggplot2)

num_ids <- 30

generate_data_for_id <- function(id) {
  num_observations <- sample(1:20, 1)
  distances <- runif(num_observations, min = 1, max = 5)  
  cumulative_distances <- cumsum(distances)
  time_since_release <- seq_len(num_observations) - 1
  sex <- sample(c("female", "male"), 1) 
  
  data.frame(
    ID = rep(id, num_observations),  
    Distance = distances,
    Cumulative_Distances_km = cumulative_distances,
    Time_Since_Release = time_since_release,
    Sex = rep(sex, num_observations)
  )
}

all_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:num_ids, generate_data_for_id))

all_data_female <- subset(all_data, all_data$Sex=="female")
all_data_male <- subset(all_data, all_data$Sex=="male")

Here is how I've represented my data
female_dist_max <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = all_data_female, aes(x = Time_Since_Release, 
            y = Cumulative_Distances_km, color = as.factor(ID)), 
            size = 0.4, linetype="dashed", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(data = all_data_female, aes(x = Time_Since_Release, 
   y = Cumulative_Distances_km, group = 1), method = "loess", 
       color = "#f8766dff", size = 0.7, se = TRUE, span = 1) + 
  labs(x = "Time_since_release (days)", 
       y = "Cumulative distance (km)", color = "ID") +
  theme_minimal() 
print(female_dist_max)

male_dist_max <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = all_data_male, aes(x = Time_Since_Release, 
  y = Cumulative_Distances_km, color = as.factor(ID)), size = 0.4, 
  linetype="dashed", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_smooth(data = all_data_male, aes(x = Time_Since_Release, 
  y = Cumulative_Distances_km, group = 1), method = "loess", 
  color = "#f8766dff", size = 0.7, se = TRUE, span = 1) +
  labs(x = "Time_since_release (days)", 
       y = "Cumulative distance (km)", color = "ID") +
  theme_minimal() 

print(male_dist_max)

I would like another method to represent these distances and test the differences between males and females.

I would suggest that you calculate speed and use that as dependent variable. You cannot model cumulative distance directly because of the inherent autocorrellation. I'm not sure which distribution family should be used. Maybe start with something like fit <- gam(list(speed ~ s(time), ~ s(time)),data = all_data, family = gammals) and then extend with random effects (e.g., see this paper).
